# Sitecore mapping img with a page

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

I have an img and some details of the img such as title description and so on.
I have a page that will display all the information of that img . Beside that I have a component to display just the title and IMG only.

When the user clicks on the img in the component, it will redirect to the page that will display all the information about the img.

What I have thought of is to map directly. But it is nice to pass some paraneters,coz I will have a very large amount of images, but I'm not sure what kind of parameter should I pass?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To me it is not clear what you want wuth the parameter and the image?

Comment: I agree with Martijn, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  What do you mean by "map directly", and why would you need to pass parameters?

Comment: If I am understanding this, when you click on the image you want the page to post to another page with some params?

Comment: My understanding is that he wants a page which lists all the images, perhaps with some small thumbnails with a title. Then when the user clicks the thumbnail they are taken to a page which will display the full size image and some additional info such as title, description, meta-data, whatever. This is pretty basic functionality, he shouldn't need to pass any parameters if he has his architecture correct, it can just be a URL link to the Sitecore Item directly, since he has additional information with each picture it cannot be just items in the media library, he will need a new template.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing is to actually ask how the component that has the link is being created. It could be a repeater.. or even a stand alone sublayout or rendering or whatever.  Any way you look at it, then you're using an Item as a datasource and just displaying fields from the datasource (i.e. the item that displays all the data about the Image which can be a Sitecore Item or even the Media Library item if you're just displaying the default library field data).  As long as your component has a datasource that is the item, you don't need to pass any parameters and can databind to a datasource and linking to the original item with something like

```
LinkManager.GetItemUrl(DataSource);
```